# Node buffer to HTMLImageElement src

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, electron

I have the following function:

```
public pasteToLayer(image: Electron.NativeImage) {
    let img = new Image();
    console.time('toString');
    img.src = 'data:image/png;base64,' + image.toPNG().toString('base64');
    console.timeEnd('toString');
}
```

When I do the logging, it takes this long to run the `toString()`:

> Image Size: 720x720
>   toString: 1221.828ms

I tried another larger image:

> Image Size: 3526x2254
>   toString: 30133.595ms

Is there a faster way for me to convert an `Electron.NativeImage` or a Node `Buffer` to an image that a javascript `HTMLImageElement` can use? When I test this in my electron application, it seems slow.

My end goal is to draw the image onto a canvas.

Comment: I think even drawing it on the canvas is better

Comment: I am trying to draw it on the canvas. I am getting the image from the clipboard, which returns a native image, so I am trying to draw that onto a canvas. I think I need to get it into an image object first before I can transfer it to the canvas. Am I wrong about that?

Comment: I don't know in what format does a Buffer store the image, but if you're lucky, and it stores the pixel information, then you can simply use the canvas' set/getdata functions

Comment: When I dumped the buffer to the console, it was an array of numbers, however I don't know if that was an array of pixel data.

Comment: Was every number between 0 and 255?

Comment: It seemed to look like it was, I didn't see anything over 255 in the first 200 items.

Comment: Then those are pixels

Comment: There are 3 operation in `img.src = 'data:image/png;base64,' + image.toPNG().toString('base64');` : convert to png, convert to string and finally assignment. Can be to measure the time of each operation?